# Customizing RazorViewEngine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razorengine, project-structure, directory-structure

Is it possible in Asp.Net MVC4 to create a file structure similar to this one:

Areas/Finance/**Base**/Product/

- ProductController.cs
- Views (folder)
- Models (folder)

Note that **Base** is a variable. There will be another folder called **Documents**, etc.

Comment: see this : http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/04/areas-in-aspnetmvc.aspx/ and this : http://developmentpassion.blogspot.nl/2014/10/aspnet-mvc-adding-custom-direcotry-for.html

Comment: That is fine, sir, however I was tackling another problem here. My question would be if the RazorViewEngine can reference the path of a controller.
For example if the controller is in Areas/Finance/Base/Product,
then the views are in {controllerDirectory}/Views